# How to split random numbers in C and get a frequency count of each digit without using an array?

Tags: c, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Use these variables in a switch statement to count each digit.
    int x0 = 0, x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0, x5 = 0,
        x6 = 0, x7 = 0, x8 = 0, x9 = 0, num;  

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        num = rand() % 1000;
        printf("%d\n", num);

        switch (num % 10) { // Splits third digit and counts.
          case 0: x0++; break;
          case 1: x1++; break;
          case 2: x2++; break;
          case 3: x3++; break;
          case 4: x4++; break;
          case 5: x5++; break;
          case 6: x6++; break;
          case 7: x7++; break;
          case 8: x8++; break;
          case 9: x9++; break;
        }

        switch (num / 10 % 10) {  // Splits second digit and counts.
          // add case statements
        }

        switch (num / 100 % 10) {  // Splits first digit and counts.
          // add case statements
        }
    }
    printf("You have %d 0 digits.\n", x0);  // Testing
    printf("You have %d 1 digits.\n", x1);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to generate 200 random numbers between 0-999, split them into digits and get a frequency count of each digit without using any arrays. I played around and figured out how to split a single number (in reverse order) and how to generate the random numbers. Now how do I split all 200 numbers and store those digits in variables I can get a count with? Do I want three variables maybe named `digit1`, `digit2`, `digit3`?

Note: This is for homework so I'm not allowed to use arrays and must use a `switch` statement for frequency counting of each digit.

Comment: You need 10 variables to store the counts, e.g. count0, count1, ... count9. The digits can be extracted in a loop, unless you're not allowed to use loops :/

Comment: I am allowed to use loops, thankfully lol.

Comment: You should not be allowed to throw so many line feeds and badly placed spaces in a source file `:-)`

Comment: Does number `0` count as an instance of digit `0`?

Comment: Yes it does. Digits are 0-9.

Comment: But number `1` should not count as one instance of `1` and 2 instances of `0`?

Comment: @Olaf The problem is not so much the the homework constraint:  it's there to let the students learn the basic, but rather asking us to do so simple homework without trying to do it.

Comment: @Christophe Trust me, you can show the constructs without ressorting to nonsense tasks and constraints. but that requires the teacher herself to have some programming skills.

Comment: @Christophe I have tried it. Don't take a jab at me without knowing what you're saying.

Comment: @NickM ok: where's your switch in your code ?  Note that I don't say this to blame you. But I really encourage you to try to solve simple exercises on your own if you want to make progress in your skills.

Comment: @Christophe I deleted it out of the original code because I do not know what to give it as an argument. How do I store each one of those 200 numbers and then give each number to a switch statement so that it can increment each number based on the digits that number contains without an array? This is the part holding me up right now.

Comment: If you can't have an array, you will not store the 200 numbers.  You would perform your statistics within the loop.  Are you allowed to define functions ?

Comment: Have not learned functions yet in C, so I would say no. I have implemented my case statements but am getting some weird test results. I will try and post an edit.

Comment: I reformatted your code for better readability. Good presentation is essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to split the number into digits. Instead of just printing the digit, use the splitting expression in a `switch` statement and add 10 `case` clauses each of which will increment a different variable.  You will need 10 variables since you cannot use array.  Do it again for the higher digits, either in a loop if you can use that or by duplicating the `switch` statement and clauses.  You may want to stop early if the random number is smaller than `10` or `100`.

Add definitions for the 10 counters and initialize them to `0`. Move the counting code inside the generating loop, and add a printing loop at the end. If you stop early, the stats should show a bias against digit `0`, otherwise all digits should show pretty close counts, but ramdomness can produce variations, and these are not abnormal, just improbable.

Comment: This is the idea I had to solve it before I put any code down. I am just not sure how to take each one of those 200 numbers and give each to the switch statement individually as the loop iterates. I need some way to store each number which makes a lot of sense using an array to do so. But without one? Can I just assign `rand() % 1000` to a variable inside the `for` loop?

Comment: @NickM: you do not need to store the 200 random numbers, just store the current one into a `num` variable and use that to extract each digit and switch on the digit. Write all these steps inside the main `for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)` loop.

Comment: I implemented the case statements, but am definitely getting some inconsistent counts when I test.

Comment: To answer your earlier question. If one of the random numbers generated is 6, then yes it's counted as having 2 zero digits and 1 six digit.

Comment: @NickM: in your updated code you print a random number, then you get another number for the digit count, that would explain the inconsistent results.

Comment: Derp! So I was creating twice as many random numbers and just couldn't see them since I was only printing off half of them. Makes sense. Thank you. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think questions of the form "Write this simple program without using <random collection of features>" belong on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Anyway, here is my solution to "count the frequency of digits in a set of 200 three-digit numbers without using an array":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
  static const unsigned long long mask = 040404040404040404040;
  unsigned long long hibits = 0, lobits = 0;
  srand(time(0));

  for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    unsigned r = rand() % 1000;
    do
      lobits += 1ULL << (6 * (r % 10)); 
    while (r /= 10);
    unsigned long long carries = lobits & mask;
    hibits += carries >> 5;
    lobits -= carries;
  }

  for (int d = 0; d < 10; ++d, lobits>>=6, hibits>>=6)
    printf("%d:%4llu\n", d, ((hibits & 077) << 5) + (lobits & 037));
  return 0;
}
```

It will be observed that the maximum frequency it can handle is 2047, since it uses a total of 11 bits for each frequency, arranged in two vectors of 10 chunks of six bits each. For simplicity, I use the high order bit of the low order chunk to only hold the carry. With a bit more work, it would be possible to use all 12 bits, but the OP only requires counting up to 600, so 11 bits is more than enough.

I would recommend *not* submitting this as a solution to your homework problem.

Comment: *With a bit more work*... I love your unintended puns.

Comment: The OP is specifically required to use a `switch` statement, can you come up with a tailored Duff device for this?

Comment: @chqrlie: You could just add `switch (0) { default: /* The following counts the frequency of a digit */ ; }` somewhere :)

Comment: The `do/while` correclty implements the early bailout for small numbers, but I'm not sure it is required.  The resulting stats are less informative with early bailout.

Comment: @chqrlie: Yeah. My original version didn't do that, but then I thought it was probably what was wanted. The history shows the old version.

Comment: Reserving a bit for the carry makes it possible to get away with just incrementing `lobits` in the loop, and then rectifying the carry afterwards. Maybe I should have said that somewhere in the answer.

Comment: Great story. Let me pull up a seat and watch the masters work.

Comment: Really impressive !  I admit that if I would find such a snippet in some code, it would take me a while before realizing that you just count digits ;-)